# Raw SQL query and return the results from database multiple columns c# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I have a database and I need to pull data from it to WinForm. I can pull data from one column but I need from multiple columns. How to do this on Entity Framework.
This is my code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var context = new spEntities()) 
    {
        var Da2 = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select distinct kg from spower ").ToList<string>();
        listBox3.DataSource = Da2;

    }
}
```

And This is what I need:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var context = new spEntities()) 
    {
        var Da2 = context.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select distinct  kg,rep from spower ").ToList<string>();
        listBox3.DataSource = Da2;

    }
}
```

What would be easiest or the best way to get data from multiple columns.

Comment: I would start with models. Are you doing code first or database first? Otherwise you may as well just use ADO.NET.

Comment: I do database first. And I can pull one column at the time but when I do a query for 2 or more columns I'm getting an exception. String don't know what to do if is more than one value.

Comment: The exception is:  The data reader has more than one field. Multiple fields are not valid for EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: Sorted I did find solution in this link:  https://www.thoughtco.com/use-sqlite-from-a-c-application-958255

Comment: Well, yes, that is ADO.NET. I would go with Gert's link at the top since you are using EF.

Comment: Steve Greene I did tried Gert's link but it didn't work for me. So I just decided to go old school ADO.NET. Don't know what I'm doing wrong but if using Gert's link method I'm getting null from a database query.

Comment: The names need to match exactly. That's still a workaround from the intended ORM nature of EF where you can simply access your entities with code like `context.Foo.Where(f => f.Type == "Bar");`